# Why I can't use await in async function constructor in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

*Well, I'm needing to run asynchronous code through a string. For this I am using async function constructor.*

```
 const AsyncFunction = Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () { }).constructor; // This returns an async function class

const stringCode = "await console.log('hello')";

new AsyncFunction(stringCode)();
```

**The problem:**

despite being an asynchronous function, when I use any await in the stringCode, it returns:

```
[ERROR] 21:21:00 SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.
```

So why can't I execute await in the async function constructor?

**Edit --**
This code snippet works on frontend pages (with normal javascript), but on nodejs(v16.14.0) it returns this error. Ironically, at the end of the documentation in the compatibility section it says that this code works from version 7.6 of node.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction#specifications)

ps: I'm not using eval because it gives access to other variables in the code, this is insane for the system security, so I'm using the asyncFuntion constructor because it doesn't allow that

Comment: I copy your code and run it on devtools and it works fine.

Comment: Also why not just use `eval`?

Comment: No reason for `Object.getPrototypeOf` (`const AsyncFunction = async function(){}.constructor;` works just as fine), but either way, the code in your question **does not throw an error** as you claim. It works exactly as it is supposed to be. Please [edit] your question to show the actual code.

Comment: Hello again folks, well I forgot to measure that I am running this code in Node.js (v16.14.0). I tried this code on a front end page and indeed, as some people are saying, the code actually works. It works perfectly, the question now is, why can't I run this code in nodeJS?? I will edit my question now

Comment: You might as well use `eval` if you're not going to run this in a separate execution context (e.g. process / worker / etc.) and serialize/deserialize messages. Using the function constructor method still gives the evaluated code access to everything at the top level scope: don't be deceived into thinking it's safe.

Comment: @jsejcksn thats not really a solution, their goal is to get an AsyncFunction. I don't know if they are doing it in their real code, but I await the async function so I can get the result.